# Dojo Charting not able to add axis

Tags: dojox.charting, dojo

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn4tT/

```
var data= [ {"a":2, "b":5,"c":3 },
            {"a":5, "b":15,"c":7 },
            {"a":1, "b":5,"c":7 } ];

chart1.addAxis("a");
chart1.addAxis("b");      
chart1.addAxis("c");

chart1.addSeries("min", {data: data[0]}, { fill: "blue" });
chart1.addSeries("max", {data: data[1] }, { fill: "blue" });
chart1.addSeries("Answered", {data: data[2]}, { fill: "blue" });

var tip = new Tooltip(chart1, "default", {
    text: function(o){                                
        console.log(o); //no axis to the current data point
    }
});

chart1.render();
```

I can get the chart to render if I remove the addAxis above, but no matter how I add axis, on a spider type chart, it throws a "can't find axis" error.

Without the axis, it doesn't look like I can set custom tooltips (only want to show the data point, not the series and axis title). And it doesn't look like I have control of the axis labels, fonts, maxlabelsize, etc.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. I'd like to let the user chose the chart labels. And on another note i need to create a line graph that uses the variance from 0 much like the columns but in the form of a line. So it looks like i'll be editing the dojo libraries, which are not made for readability. I would love to see what you've done with the spider.js and common.js files if you'd be willing to share those with us.

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing and it would be very helpful to see your success with the spider and common files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be added as a feature in future versions of dojo, but currently after a lot of fighting with it. I cracked open the library and added custom code to handle this and a lot of other things. Basically, just opening the spider.js and common.js files used in generating the spider diagrams. Was able to wrap the labels in my own class's. And also inserted a title attribute for each with the desired label. Using an external tooltip library, I now have a lot of control over the tooltips in spider diagrams.